# MacbookPro restarts whenever I open Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, virtualization, osx-mountain-lion

I just installed the HAXM from Intel and whenever I try to open now an emulator with Intel Atom x86 CPU the computer restarts.

I am running the laptop on OSX Mountain Lion

Anyone have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: The Ghost of Steve Jobs forbids you to develop Android on a Mac. Seriously though, have you opened up the "Console" app to see what the errors are?

Comment: I get this like 200 times on the Console: 2/6/13 8:06:13.514 PM talagent[236]: CGSFlushSurfaceWithOptions: Invalid window 0x13
ANd 2/6/13 8:07:24.856 PM eclipse[343]: Unrecognized Java VM option ignored: -Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
2/6/13 8:07:24.857 PM eclipse[343]: Unrecognized Java VM option ignored: -XstartOnFirstThread
2/6/13 8:07:24.857 PM eclipse[343]: Unrecognized Java VM option ignored: -XstartOnFirstThread

Comment: IIRC there at least was some issue with the Android emulator and the screen resolution (or was it pixel density?) of retina display Macbooks.

Comment: Am using the MacBookPro for my android development i never go this problem but when you have this problem why cant you download a fresh copy of SDK and try again.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to download the hotfix found here, http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

More information may be found here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37826